# Making this logo more coherent and unique on both sides?

Tags: logo, critique

[image: logo]

The name and logo would be the basis to build a corporate and brand identity for a wholesale distribution company wanting to expand into new markets in different countries. They were developed in-house by the company.

The name would be the business name as well as a brand for products manufactured by the company, and they're looking to project a professional and modern look.

Besides fixing the kerning, I feel like the logo needs to be a little more even on both sides: all the color and accents are currently on the right side, and I feel it looks strange, but I'm looking for ideas on how to make it more coherent and unique.

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - glad to have you here. Please examine [tour] to learn about our community here, and then read through [ask] and [answer] a question, to understand what makes an appropriate query for here, and how to frame it for best results. I'd also strongly recommend you looking at this meta post about how to correctly ask for critiques: [https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/682#682]
Feel free once you've read these to then edit your question as needed.

Comment: Hi jukkali, I think you should add information about the conceptual meaning of the logo. As your question is formulated now, the only possible answers will be regarding formal aspects without any base or meaning. We don`t know anything about the typography election, the colors, the graphics, what the image represents... Unless you want to know how to correctly integrate a tricolor tongue at the end of a word ;-)

Comment: Also I would recommend you reading some [logo critiques questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=logo+critique) in this site.

Comment: I don't think it needs much more than the kerning addressed. Simplicity has merit.

Answer (score -2):

It's a difficult problem. I would try to go back to who they are and what image they are trying to project. They should be able to defend the design choices and if they can't that should free you to try different things. Create a moodboard, invite them to participate, ask them for a list of adjectives that best describe what they want. You are helping them to sell an idea. A great logo should represent that idea. Get a sketchbook and don't be afraid to doodle, even if you cannot draw. You can always fix it later. Try doing thumbnails. Try doing a favicon. Try doing an app icon. Try to have fun!

Comment: How does this answer the question being asked? It's just general advice